# How can I run ENTRYPOINT as root user?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is a part of my dockerfile:

```
COPY ./startup.sh /root/startup.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/startup.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/root/startup.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]

USER jenkins
```

I have to switch in the end to USER jenkins and i have to run the container as jenkins.

My Question is now how can I run the startup.sh as root user when the container starts?

Comment: try this `CMD ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe", "&& su - jenkins"]`

Comment: When I do this i am getting an other error: mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended -------->
I think that the command mysqld_safe is done by user jenkins. Any further tips?

Answer (score 19):

Delete the `USER jenkins` line in your Dockefile.

Change the user at the end of your entrypoint script (`/root/startup.sh`).

by adding: `su - jenkins` [man su](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/su1.html)

**Example:**

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM debian:8

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash exemple

COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT "/root/entrypoint.sh"
```

*entrypoint.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I am root" && id

su - exemple

# needed to run parameters CMD
$@
```

Now you can run

```
$ docker build -t so-test .
$ docker run --rm -it so-test bash
I am root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
exemple@37b01e316a95:~$ id
uid=1000(exemple) gid=1000(exemple) groups=1000(exemple)
```

It's just a simple example, you can also use the `su -c` option to run command with changing user.

Comment: This should mean when I e.g. run: docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> /bin/bash     ------ i should be the jenkins user?

Comment: My preference is an `exec gosu` rather than an `su` command, to handle signals.

Comment: @BMitch Can you give an example?

Comment: This gets the job done, the only thing is that when running docker exec -it <CONTAINER-ID> /bin/bash, we will be the root user, which is kind of annoying, I guess. Any solutions?

Comment: @qichao_he This doesn't really answers your question, but when using docker-compose it is possible to add `user: jenkins` in the `docker-compose.yml` file, then running in terminal: `docker-compose exec {service-name} /bin/bash`

Comment: In the beginning, I thought this was the perfect solution. The idea of having a non-root user is for security reasons. We this approach you are keeping the root user always.

Comment: @qichao_he $docker exec -u <USERNAME> -it <CONTAINER-ID> /bin/bash

Comment: How does this work?  Why doesn't su do what it normally does and try to open an interactive shell, with the script continuing as root once the shell terminates?