# Docker exec with other than root user but ENTRYPOINT runs with root user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run the docker exec it is always `root` user.

The requirement is to always docker exec other than `root` user still the entrypoint needs to run `root` some of the sshd config changes and it's restarting. I can't change the user permissions as well to accommodate to change ssh config

is there way to remove root user from bash when I did `su` in entrypoint.sh

When I do docker exec it should be an example user only,  I understand that it is only possible through `USER` command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

I have tried multiple solutions with docker and dokcer-composer still no success.

For example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410394/358458

I am just copying and pasting some of the content to understand my question more.

`Dokcerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash exemple

COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT "/root/entrypoint.sh"
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
id
echo 'Banner /usr/bin/custom-banner' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
rm -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_*

su - exemple
cd /home/example
id
```

```
$ docker build -t so-test .
$ docker run --rm -it so-test bash
I am root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
exemple@37b01e316a95:~$ id
uid=1000(exemple) gid=1000(exemple) groups=1000(exemple)
```

Comment: Anyone who can run `docker exec` can pretty trivially use Docker to root the host; they can if nothing else add themselves to the host's `/etc/sudoers` file and manually poke around in the Docker data directory.  They could also replace this container with a different one injecting different configuration files.  You can't really restrict `docker exec` at all.

Comment: (I wouldn't normally recommend running sshd in a container at all.  It looks like you're thinking about things like host keys, which is better than many setups, but it's usually easier to operate an administer a container like you would the single process it runs.  That might simplify the overall Docker setup, though you still can't prevent `exec` as root into it.)

Comment: Thanks for inputs, I think I am not worried ssh part, I am looking little hack that executes the entry point with root user, while docker user had limited permissions.